# Shader Class Implementation

Tags: c++, opengl

Well trying to design a shader class, for now just trying to get basic outline for handling uniforms. Some design goals I aimed for is to avoid passing a string to a function as this is error prone and has no type checking. There's only really one place this can go wrong and there's if you mistype the name of the uniform when defining it.

There is a lot of potential for code bloat though, could potentially move the Name out of the template parameters for Parameter and store it as a member variable which would get assigned in the default constructor.

```
template<typename ParamType>
class Shader
{
public:
    template<typename Type, const char* (*Name)()>
    class Parameter
    {
        static const char* name;
        static GLuint location;
        static GLuint program;

        template<typename> friend class Shader;
    };

    template<typename Type, const char* (*Name)()>
    void SetParameter(const Parameter<Type,Name>&, const Type& value )
    {
        // static_assert(!std::is_same<Type,Type>::value, "Unsupported type, needs specialization.");
        typedef Parameter<Type,Name> Param;

        if(program != -1 && Param::program != program)
        {
            // set Param::location
            Param::program = program;
        }

        std::cout << Param::name << std::endl;
    }

private:

    GLuint program;

};

template<typename ParamType>
template<typename Type, const char* (*Name)()>
const char* Shader<ParamType>::Parameter<Type, Name>::name = Name();

template<typename ParamType>
template<typename Type, const char* (*Name)()>
GLuint Shader<ParamType>::Parameter<Type, Name>::program = -1;

#include "shaderparameters.inl"
```

shaderparameters.inl:

```
#define MY_PARAMETER(shader, type, name) \
    private: static const char* ShaderParameterStr##shader##type##name##() { return #name ; }  \
    public:  typedef Shader< shader >::Parameter< type, &ShaderParameterStr##shader##type##name > name;

struct ShaderParam
{
    struct Generic
    {
        MY_PARAMETER( Generic, Vec4, position )
        MY_PARAMETER( Generic, Mat4, projection )
    };

};
#undef MY_PARAMETER
```

Usage:

```
Shader<ShaderParam::Generic> s;

s.SetParameter(ShaderParam::Generic::projection(), Mat4());
s.SetParameter(ShaderParam::Generic::position(), Vec4());
```

What are you thoughts on this implementation ? Do you have suggestions for improvements or perhaps an entirely different system ? I know I've seen people use hash maps and such but there's still the problem of continuously using a string literial to set the uniforms and such (don't really like the thought of using a Macro to define the string either).

Comment: Heh so take the question as how to implement a shader class that doesn't take a string as a parameter.

Comment: Shaders are supposed to be flexible. You're better off keeping everything loose using strings/gluints/enums as the arguments. Wrap a type safety layer around it for specific use cases if you want instead and keep your generic shader class open for different kinds of designs.

Comment: It's not adding any constraints, you simply replace a string with a class that defines the string so you create the class instead of the string avoiding mistypes with no error checking.

Comment: You may have the wrong idea if your shader class contains a program. It is kind of the other way around. Programs contain one or more shader per-stage (vertex/fragment are required, other stages are optional). In other APIs (and OpenGL with Separate Shader Objects) the notion of a linked program does not exist, but I would still consider "program" to subsume the characteristics of the shaders they are composed of and not the other way around; another more API agnostic name for a "program" might be "pipeline".

Comment: I was planning on having some sort of Shader::Component class where you would load the actual sources from and use them to build programs (Shader in this case). Pipeline would probably be a better name for the class.